# Adds a clickable element in the select tag(<select>)

Tags: javascript, css

I have a question regarding a drop-down menu. But it is difficult to explain. I would like to make a drop-down menu `<select>` as shown in the picture below and for every `<option>`, I should create a question mark (?) at the right side. As you see in the picture, the purpose is to show a small explanation of that `<option>` when we place the mouse cursor on each option's question mark. I really appreciate if anyone can help me. Thank you in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfotunately with simple `<select>` and `options` that is not possible. You have to use `<div>` as as dropdown or `<ul>`. You can also search for "custom select box plugin" in google.

Comment: something like this ?                                                                               '<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">item 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sub item 1   <p id="ddd">?</p></a><li>
                <li><a href="#">sub item 1</a><li>
                <li><a href="#">sub item 1</a><li>
            </ul>
        </li> '

Comment: Exactly. But in your example `<nav>` is redunant. Use combination of `position: absolute` and `display: none` on `ul` element.